# How to clean hair and junk off an auger?

Tags: plumbing, cleaning, clog

Afterusing an auger/snake to clean out the pipes from a shower, the tip is usually disgusting, with a large clot of hair inextricably entangled into the tip. Is there a trick to clean this thing? I used to "unwrap" the hair from the spiral tip (the boring gimlet), but frankly that takes like 10 minutes and is really gross. I have considered burning it after it dries, but...gross.

Or maybe I should use a different type of auger? All the ones I've bought at Home Depot type stores have the boring gimlet. It's the following, but with a huge tangle of stinkhair wrapped all up in there:

[image: boring gimlet]

Comment: It doesn't really matter which tip type you use, you will reliably get "stinkhair" (hate it but love that term, lol) wrapped up on it. I have found that it's much less messy and less smelly to let it dry, regardless of final removal method.

Comment: What you're supposed to do is walk the big hairy glob over to your wife and say "You're welcome"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap a rag or gloved hand around it and spin it backward. Or burn it off with a plumbing torch (outside, of course). Or dunk it in drain clog remover for a while.

Comment: Good tips, though I think I would avoid dissolving it in chemical clog remover that's overkill. :)

Answer (score 4):

I always let mine dry and then take it out back and put the torch to it. It does leave some residue, which is very easily and quickly removed with a wire brush.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware if you use torch lightly burn hair with out putting heat to the snake. If you overheat the spring in the metal it becomes brittle and will break in future use.

Comment: This is missing a few words here and there that would make it much easier to read. You may consider an [edit] to improve legibility.

Answer (score 1):

Use a straight razor, a new one, nice and sharp, and slice one sige of the hair clog if it goes past the bit and onto the shaft.

Otherwise, unscrew from the bit.

Answer (score 1):

All great tips. Thank you. I don't own a blow torch, so I improvised using pointers above. Let it dry. Then, put on gloves. I used needle nose pliers to unscrew and tear hair off. After most of hair removed, I used a razer tool to scrape off the remaining hair. With hair in between spiral tip, I used the razer in between the coils to cut through. Then I pulled off the hair/residue with my gloved hands or the pliers.